# I need clarification about DFA's and DFA acceptable languages

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

In class yesterday we went over DFA's and DFA acceptable languages.  An example of a language that is not DFA acceptable was given as $\{ ab, aabb, aaabbb, aaaabbbb, \ldots \}$.  The reason given was that the machine would need an infinite amount of states.

But wouldn't a simple DFA that has only one state that is a final state and loops back to itself on all inputs accept that language?

Also in class we discussed how the complement of a DFA acceptable language is also DFA acceptable simply by swapping the final states and the non-final states.  But if you had the language $L = \{ a \}$, over the alphabet $\{ a, b \}$, then obviously $L$ is DFA acceptable, but the complement of $L$ is $\{ a, b \}^* - \{ a \}$, which includes $\{ ab, aabb, aaabbb, \ldots \}$.

I think I must be misunderstanding something crucial here.

Comment: The one-state automaton you describe would accept every possible input, not just the ones of the form $a^nb^n$.

Comment: So I think my problem is in the definition of accepting a language.  The machine must accept all of the strings in L and nothing else to accept L.  Is this correct?

Comment: The language a DFA accepts is defined as the set if all strings it accepts. So "accepting a language" *just means* accepting only that language.

Comment: I see thank you.  Now it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $Doubt-1$:  "But wouldn't a simple DFA that has only one state that is a final state and loops back to itself on all inputs accept that language?"

No, the DFA you are thinking about as below: accepts $(a + b)^*$ that is "all possible string consists of symbols '$a$' and '$b$', including $ε$ string".

```
     __
     ||  a, b
     ▼| 
––►((Q0))

Q0 is both initial and final state
```

Language accepted by this DFA is superset of language $L = \{ a^nb^n$ | $n > 0  \}$  and hance also accepts all strings in $L$.

The concept you are missing is:
 "An automata $A$ for some language $L$ must accept $\textit{exactly}$  language $L$, neither a subset nor a superset of $L$".

Hance DFA above is not a finite representation of language $L = \{ a^nb^n$ | $n > 0 \}$.

> $Doubt-2$:  "Also in class we discussed how the complement of a DFA acceptable language is also DFA acceptable simply by swapping the final states and the non-final states".

**Note**: To construct new complement DFA $D$, old-DFA $A$ must be a complete, means there should all possible outgoing edge from each state (or in other words [δ should be a complete function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14940382/1673391)). 
Read ["Complement DFA for Regular Expression $(00 + 1)^*$"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802732/finding-the-complement-of-a-dfa/14817545#14817545) to learn how to consturct complement DFA.

> $Doubt-3$:   But if you had the language $L = \{ a \}$, over the alphabet $\{ a, b \}$, then obviously $L$ is DFA acceptable, but the complement of $L$ is $\{ a, b \}^* - \{ a \}$, which includes $\{ ab, aabb, aaabbb, \ldots \}$.

As you already know complement of a regular language is regular (DFA exists for regular language and you know how to make DFA for complement regular language), so new language $L^" $ = $\{ a, b \}^* - \{ a \}$ is a regular language.

And language $L^" $  is a superset of language $\{ a^nb^n$ | $n > 0 \}$.

The concept you are missing is that you don't know:

> $Doubt-4$:   *"What is called regular language?"* And Why a languages like $(a + b)^*$  is regular? But language $\{ a^nb^n$ | $n > 0 \}$ is *not* a regular language**

A language (a set) $L$ is called Regular Language, if its require bounded (finite) amount of information at any instance of time while processing a strings in language $L$.

**What is *bounded* information?**
For example: Consider a fan switch for `on-off`. By viewing fan-switch we can say whether fan is in `on` or `off` state (this is bounded or limited information).
But we can not know that how many times a fan has been on-off in past! (to memorized, it requires a mechanism to store *unbounded* amount of information to count how many times  – e.g. some kind of meters, we have in our car/bike).

To understand how states are uses as memory element read this answer, you may also like to read: [How to write regular expression for a DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717)

Language $\{ a^nb^n$ | $n > 0 \}$ is **not** a regular because here $n$ is unbounded. To verify string in language $a^nb^n$ we have to remember how many '$a$' has been came and this required a infinite memory to count because number of '$a$' s in string that can be infinity large.
(hence an automata can only capable to process strings of $a^nb^n$ if it has infinite memory e.g PDA).

Whereas $(a + b)^*$ is of-course a regular by its nature, because there is bounded restriction that "string consists of only symbol '$a$' and '$b$'".
 And strings of this language can be easily processed (or recognized) by an automata in which we have finite memory that is **finite automata**. Yes, in finite automata we have finite memory in terms of states (The word "Finite" significance of the presence of 'finite amount of memory' in the form of finite number of states $Q$).

Summarize:

*Memory in finite automata is present in the form of states $Q$ only and according to automata principal: any automata can have only finite set of states. hence finite automata has finite memory, this is the reason automata for regular language is called finite automata. You can think a finite automata like CPU without memory, that has finite  register to remember its internal states*.

Finite State  –► Finite Memory  –► Only language can be process for which finite memory need to store at any instance of time while processing the string: –► that language is called Regular Language

Absence of external memory is limitation of finite automate  –► or we can say limitation of class of language defined by finite automata that is called Regular language.

**Side note:**:
*   Also a language { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | 10<sup>>100</sup> n > 0 } is regular, a large set but regular because $n$ is bounded, hence finite automata and regular expression is possible for this language  – finite set is always regular.
*  There are infinite sets those are regular. Regular language of subset of all possible infinite set. Check this [Venn-diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803894/finiteness-of-regular-language/20818068#20818068).

So, if any time you need to proof that a language $L$ not a regular – before the go to use "formal tools" likes pumping lemma, first try to proof using fundamental definition of regular language.

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize the answers given in the comments to the question.

An automaton $A$ accepts a language $L$ if it accepts each word in $L$ and rejects each word not in $L$. Each automaton $A$ accepts a unique language $L$ which consists of all words accepted by $A$. Therefore, while the one-state automaton accepting $\{a,b\}^*$ does accept all the words in $L = \{a^n b^n : n \geq 0\}$, it does not accept $L$ since it also accepts other words such as $b$.

For completeness, here is the proof that an automaton for $L$ would require infinitely many states, or more formally, that no DFA accepts $L$. Suppose there was some DFA $A$ accepting $L$. Let $s_n$ be the state that $A$ is in after reading $a^n$. I claim that $s_n \neq s_m$ for all $n \neq m$. Indeed, starting at $s_n$ and reading $b^n$, the automaton $A$ ends up in an accepting state since $a^n b^n \in L$. If $s_m = s_n$ then this means that $A$ would accepts $a^n b^m \notin L$. This contradiction shows that $s_n \neq s_m$ for all $n \neq m$, and so $A$ must contain infinitely many states, which it can't since DFAs have finitely many states. So no DFA accepts $L$.

For a generalization, check out the [Myhill–Nerode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Acceptance of a Language $L$(regular): means there is a finite accepter that accept all strings $w$ belongs to L and reject all strings not in $L$.

An example of a language that is not DFA acceptable is $L=\{ab,aabb,aaabbb,aaaabbbb,…\}$.The question is why: there can be a finite accepter for all the strings w belongs to L but that finite accepter can also accept those strings that do not belong to L. So according to the definition of acceptance, there can't be a finite accepter for $L$.

Finite accepter (DFA and NFA) can't accept these language because to accept these kind of languages the machine need infinite memory to store number of $a$'s and $b$'s(Since number of a and b is unbounded, we require storing an unbounded amount of information). But Finite automata do not have temporary storage capability. There is a more capable Automata named Pushdown Automata that can recognize this language.(This language is known as context free language)

The language $L=\{a\}$ is definitely DFA acceptable because there can be a finite accepter that only accept the string $a$. But complement of $L$ not only includes $ab,aabb,aaabbb,…$ these strings. It also includes strings $b$, $aab$, $abb$,$aabbb$ etc. And simply by swapping the final states and the non-final states of the DFA for $L$ you can get a finite accpter that accepts the language which is complement of $L$ .

Comment: Change: "need some memory to store number" --> " need infinite memory to store number".

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: edited.

Comment: Tan My comment means: second line in second para. replace 'some' --> 'infinite' , because $n$ in $a^nb^n$  can be infinitely large.