# If L is not regular and is a proper subset of L1, does it follow that L1 is not regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

If $L$ is not regular and $ L \subset L_1$, does it follow that $L_1$ is not regular also? Can you please provide an explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Patterns in the class of regular languages are *less* restricted than non-regular languages (CFLs, CSLs). my [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23470/5000) to another question may help ...

Answer (score 18):

[@Vladislav's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/123316/4416) is probably more interesting, but observe that *every* language over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$, which is certainly a regular language.

Comment: Actually I had the same in mind, just presented a specific example for illustration purposes.

Comment: This is the most elegant and definitive answer possible.  A machine that accepts *any* input certainly accepts a regular language, of which all others on the same alphabet are proper subsets.

Answer (score 8):

No. Let $L$ be the language of balanced bracket sequences, and $L_1$ be the language of arbitrary bracket sequences. Then $L \subset L_1$, $L$ is not regular (you can prove it using [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)), but $L_1$ is clearly regular.